# Using Buffer Ports in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Is it bad coding practice to use Buffer Ports in VHDL?

I define an entity with an out port with o_done.

```
entity blahblah is
  port (
...other signals...
 o_done    : out std_logic;              
  );
end entity blahblah;
```

The synthesizer does not like me reading an out port and wont synthesize it - even though it is legal VHDL 2008 code.  I can't change my synthesizer.

I use o_done in 2 clocked processes:

```
process begin
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    if (reset = '1') then
      o_done <= '0';
    else
      if ( State1 ) then
        o_done <= '1';
      elsif ( o_done = '1' AND State0 ) then
        o_done <= '1';
      else
        o_done <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  process begin
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    if (reset = '1') then
      count <= to_unsigned(0, 8);
    else
      if( stateS0 AND done = '1' ) then
        count <= to_unsigned(0, 8);
      elsif( stateS1 AND y_counter >= 2 AND p >= 0 ) then
        count <= count + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
```

Again, o_done, since defined as out in the port declaration, is not synthesizable since the synthesis engine isn't fully VHDL 2008 compatible.  I can't change the synthesizer.

So how do I work around o_done being an output port and wanting to read it ?

Can I make an intermediate signal - how do I do this typically ?

Comment: Buffer ports as in GPIO? Or buffering signals?

Comment: The question is not clear to the community. You can say why you wanted to use buffer port with a code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, you can use the simple solution of creating an internal signal:

```
signal done : std_logic ;
```

Use this signal inside your clocked process.

And simply assign it to `o_done` as a concurrent statement inside architecture definition:

```
o_done <= done ;
```

I haven't really had the need to use buffer ports in VHDL codes till now. This is something I extracted from Xilinx Vivado Synthesis Guide:

> VHDL allows buffer port mode when a signal is used both internally,
> and as an output port when there is only one internal driver. Buffer
> ports are a potential source of errors during synthesis, and
> complicate validation of post-synthesis results through simulation.
> reference: [Chapter 5, Xilinx Vivado Synthesis Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)

Comment: Attempted this but the problem is that o_done value and then done value is state so i am not sure how to define done when it is state dependent.

Comment: Both done and o_done will transit exactly the same. Both are same signals technically on hardware even though with different names.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, thanks.  I had to modify the statement for the state dependence.

Comment: Yea, but his synthesiser doesn't support VHDL-2008. Must be pretty old synthesiser then.

Comment: No actually it is a 2019 synthesizer.  And it doesnt support VHDL 2008.  I wont say the company though.  Due to my setup, I can't change the setting of the synthesizer.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some switches. Sometimes you have to manually specify that you want to use VHDL-2008 while compiling.